# datatables.net select first row in initComplete selects wrong row with default sort

Tags: datatables

I want to select first row in the table. I do so in the initComplete-event:

```js
"initComplete": function() {
  var t = $(gridId).DataTable();
  t.row(0).select();
}
```

This works fine, but if I get the data unsorted and I implement a default ordering, the wrong row is selected because it's not the first row one anymore.

```js
"order": [[ 2, "desc" ]]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [**selector-modifier**](https://datatables.net/reference/type/selector-modifier) `{ order: 'current' }` :

```js
...
initComplete: function() {
   this.api().row( {order: 'current' }, 0).select();
}
```

This will select the first row regardless of ordering and sorting.

demo -> **http://jsfiddle.net/cr49g371/**